# Hive DB doesnt save the nested objects

Tags: flutter

Hello I have an app which user can create subcategories for the main categories. When user created main category, main object saves to the database, after I re-open app I can see them, But when I created for subcategory for specified main category, I can see in the sub category screen, But when I re-open the app I can see the only main categories, I guess subcategories cant save to the DB, I use Hive to store my datas to the phone,can someone explain why I can not save the sub-object to the DB and how can I do that. I have stucked Thanks for your help...........................................................................................................................................................

I share main categories screen where I make em displayed main categories

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({this.newCategoryName,this.newCategoryImagePath});
  final  String newCategoryImagePath;
  final  String newCategoryName;
  static String id="homeScreen";

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {


  Widget buildBottomSheet(BuildContext context)=>AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Menü Ekle",route: "homeScreen");
  int _flag=0;
  Box<CategoryModel> _categoryModelsBox;


  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _categoryModelsBox = Hive.box<CategoryModel>("categoryModelsInBox");
    if (widget.newCategoryName!=null && widget.newCategoryImagePath!=null){
      CategoryModel newCategoryModel = CategoryModel(categoryId:categoryModels.length, categoryImagePath: widget.newCategoryImagePath,
        categoryName: widget.newCategoryName,categoryColor: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(0.5).value);
      categoryModels.insert(categoryModels.length,newCategoryModel);
      _categoryModelsBox.add(newCategoryModel);
    }
  }

  Future<bool> showAlertDialog(BuildContext context){
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: kColorTheme10,
      elevation: 0,
      content: Container(decoration:BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid,width: 1),
        color: Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.7),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
      ),  child: Padding(
           padding:  EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: Text(
              "Çıkmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?",
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: "OpenSans")
          ),
      ),
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
      actions: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.7),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
          ),
          child: TextButton(onPressed:()async{
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("EVET",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: "OpenSans"),),
            )),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color:Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.7),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
          ),
          child: TextButton(onPressed:()async{
            Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("HAYIR",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: "OpenSans")),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_)=>alert);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: kColorTheme1,
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 20,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF2C3D4).withOpacity(1),
            title:TitleBorderedText(title:"Sevimli Yemekler", textColor: Color(0xFFFFFB00)),
            actions: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 27,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage(kCuttedLogoPath),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(kBGWithLogoOpacity),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child:GridView.builder (
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                          itemCount: _categoryModelsBox.length+1,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                            if(_categoryModelsBox.length==0){
                              return EmptyCard(where: "homeScreen",);
                            }
                            if(_flag==1){
                              return EmptyCard(where: "homeScreen",);
                            }
                            if(index==_categoryModelsBox.length-1){
                              _flag=1;
                              CategoryModel categoryModel = _categoryModelsBox.getAt(index);
                              return CategoryCard(category: categoryModel);
                            }
                            else{
                              CategoryModel categoryModel = _categoryModelsBox.getAt(index);
                              return CategoryCard(category: categoryModel);
                            }
                          }
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                              color: kColorTheme7,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                            ),
                            child: TextButton(
                                onPressed: (){
                                  showModalBottomSheet(
                                    isDismissible: false,
                                    enableDrag: false,
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(buttonText: "Menü Ekle",route: "homeScreen",),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: TitleBorderedText(title: "LEZZET GRUBU EKLE",textColor: Colors.white,)
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: ()async{
        var response = await showAlertDialog(context);
        print(response);
        return response;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I share main categories screen where I make em displayed sub categories of main category

```
class SubCategoriesScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  SubCategoriesScreen({this.categoryId,this.subCategoryName, this.subCategoryImagePath});
  static String id="subCategoriesScreen";
  final String subCategoryName;
  final String subCategoryImagePath;
  final int categoryId;
  Widget buildBottomSheet(BuildContext context)=>AddMenuScreen(categoryId: categoryId,buttonText: "Tarif Ekle",route: "subCategoryScreen",);


  @override
  _SubCategoriesScreenState createState() => _SubCategoriesScreenState();
}

class _SubCategoriesScreenState extends State<SubCategoriesScreen> {

  int _flag=0;
  Box<CategoryModel> _categoryModelBox;
  CategoryModel _categoryModel;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _categoryModelBox = Hive.box<CategoryModel>("categoryModelsInBox");
    _categoryModel = _categoryModelBox.getAt(widget.categoryId);
    if(widget.categoryId!=null && widget.subCategoryImagePath!=null && widget.subCategoryName!=null){
      addSubCategory();
      }
    }

    void addSubCategory()async{
      SubCategoryModel subCategoryModel=SubCategoryModel(
          subCategoryId:widget.categoryId,
          subCategoryImagePath: widget.subCategoryImagePath,
          subCategoryName: widget.subCategoryName,
          categoryColor: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(0.5).value);
      if(_categoryModel.subCategoryModels!=null){
        //for (var categoryModel in categoryModels){
          //if (categoryModel.categoryId == subCategoryModel.subCategoryId){
            //categoryModel.subCategoryModels.insert(categoryModel.subCategoryModels.length-1,subCategoryModel);
            //categoryModel.subCategoryModels.add(subCategoryModel);
            _categoryModel=_categoryModelBox.getAt(widget.categoryId);
            _categoryModel.subCategoryModels.add(subCategoryModel);
            _categoryModelBox.putAt(widget.categoryId, _categoryModel);
          //}
        //}
      }
    }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                centerTitle: true,
                title: BorderedText(
                  child:Text(
                    _categoryModel.categoryName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0XFFFFFB00),
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontFamily: "OpenSans"
                    ),
                  ),
                  strokeWidth: 5,
                  strokeColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF2C3D4).withOpacity(1),
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  iconSize: 40,
                  color: Color(0xFFA2000B),
                ),
                actions: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 27,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/cuttedlogo.PNG"),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              body:Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("images/logoBGopacity.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: GridView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                          itemCount:_categoryModel.subCategoryModels.length+1,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index){
                            if(_categoryModel.subCategoryModels.length==0){
                              return EmptyCard(where: "subCategoryScreen",categoryId: widget.categoryId,);
                            }
                            if(_flag==1){
                              return EmptyCard(where: "subCategoryScreen",categoryId: widget.categoryId,);
                            }
                            if(index==_categoryModel.subCategoryModels.length-1){
                              _flag=1;
                              SubCategoryModel subCategoryModel =_categoryModel.subCategoryModels[index];
                              return SubCategoryCard(subCategoryCardId:index,subCategoryId:subCategoryModel.subCategoryId,subcategoryName: subCategoryModel.subCategoryName,
                                subCategoryImagePath:subCategoryModel.subCategoryImagePath,
                                subCategoryCardColor: subCategoryModel.categoryColor,);
                            }
                            else{
                              SubCategoryModel subCategoryModel =_categoryModel.subCategoryModels[index];
                              return SubCategoryCard(subCategoryCardId:index,subCategoryId:subCategoryModel.subCategoryId,subcategoryName: subCategoryModel.subCategoryName,
                                subCategoryImagePath:subCategoryModel.subCategoryImagePath,
                                subCategoryCardColor: subCategoryModel.categoryColor,);
                            }
                          }
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid),
                              color: kColorTheme7,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                            ),
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: (){
                                showModalBottomSheet(
                                  isDismissible: false,
                                  enableDrag: false,
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context)=> AddMenuScreen(categoryId:widget.categoryId,buttonText: "Tarif Ekle", route:"subCategoryScreen"),
                                );
                              },
                              child: BorderedText(
                                strokeWidth: 5,
                                strokeColor: Colors.black,
                                child:Text("Tarif Ekle",style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily:'OpenSans',
                                  fontSize:30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly I share the codes of my classes and auto generated hive files.

```
part 'categoryModel.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId : 0)
class CategoryModel extends HiveObject{
  CategoryModel(
      { this.categoryId,
        this.categoryImagePath,
        this.categoryName,
        this.categoryColor});

  @HiveField(0)
  final int categoryColor;

  @HiveField(1)
  List <SubCategoryModel> subCategoryModels=[];

  @HiveField(2)
  int categoryId;

  @HiveField(3)
  String categoryImagePath;

  @HiveField(4)
  String categoryName;

}
```

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'categoryModel.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class CategoryModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<CategoryModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  CategoryModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return CategoryModel(
      categoryId: fields[2] as int,
      categoryImagePath: fields[3] as String,
      categoryName: fields[4] as String,
      categoryColor: fields[0] as int,
      //subCategoryModels: (fields[1] as List)?.cast<SubCategoryModel>()
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, CategoryModel obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.categoryColor)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.subCategoryModels)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.categoryId)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.categoryImagePath)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.categoryName);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is CategoryModelAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

```
part 'subCategoryModel.g.dart';


@HiveType(typeId : 1)
class SubCategoryModel extends HiveObject{
  SubCategoryModel({
    this.subCategoryId,
    this.subCategoryImagePath,
    this.subCategoryName,
    this.categoryColor,
    this.recipeId,
    List<Ingredient>ingredients,
    this.recipePhotoDir,
    this.recordedVoiceDir,
    bool isCompeted});

  @HiveField(0)
  final int categoryColor;

  @HiveField(1)
  final double recipeId;

  @HiveField(2)
  bool isCompleted;

  @HiveField(3)
  int subCategoryId;

  @HiveField(4)
  String subCategoryImagePath;

  @HiveField(5)
  String subCategoryName;

  @HiveField(6)
  List <Ingredient> ingredients=[] ;

  @HiveField(7)
  String recipePhotoDir;

  @HiveField(8)
  String recordedVoiceDir;

}
```

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'subCategoryModel.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class SubCategoryModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<SubCategoryModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 2;

  @override
  SubCategoryModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return SubCategoryModel(
      subCategoryId: fields[3] as int,
      subCategoryImagePath: fields[4] as String,
      subCategoryName: fields[5] as String,
      categoryColor: fields[0] as int,
      recipeId: fields[1] as double,
      ingredients: (fields[6] as List)?.cast<Ingredient>(),
      recipePhotoDir: fields[7] as String,
      recordedVoiceDir: fields[8] as String,
    )..isCompleted = fields[2] as bool;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

you may change your register adapter order.

Use

```
Hive.registerAdapter(ChildAdapter());
Hive.registerAdapter(ParentAdapter());
```

Instead of

```
Hive.registerAdapter(ParentAdapter());
Hive.registerAdapter(ChildAdapter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HiveList like that:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'mood.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Mood extends HiveObject {
  Mood({
    required this.dateCreated,
    required this.moodScale,
    required this.moodState,
    required this.notes,
  });

  @HiveField(0)
  DateTime dateCreated;
  @HiveField(1)
  int moodScale;
  @HiveField(2)
  int moodState;
  @HiveField(3)
  HiveList<Note>? notes;
}

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Note extends HiveObject {
  Note(
      {required this.noteTitle,
      required this.noteDescription,
      required this.imagePath});

  @HiveField(0)
  String noteTitle;
  String noteDescription;
  String imagePath;
}
```